# Make column only as wide as it's content

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid, row

Is there a way to tell a column in bootstrap to only be as wide as it's content?

I have a list of items. The html looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1 " style="background-color: rebeccapurple">
                <input type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-10" style="background-color: #007fff">
                Title
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color: #777620">
                "Button Group
            </div>
</div>
```

I'd like the first and last column to only be as wide as it's content.
[image: Result on the website]

Answer (score 4):

set `width:auto;` in style attribute of each `div` that you want to autosize

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 " style="background-color: rebeccapurple;width:auto;">
        <input type="checkbox">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10" style="background-color: #007fff;">
        Title
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1" style="background-color: #777620;  width:auto;">
        "Button Group
    </div>
</div>
```